# How to initialize multiple firebase projects

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to initialize multiple firebase projects in react but am getting a weird error saying ×
`Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).

I` picked a completely different string , but it's still not working. Can someone pls explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

reference.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";



  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDsTsClk8l2l5yLNu_eG-R06Usv4Oi_NvQ",
    authDomain: "d-ucukgx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://d-ucukgx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "d-ucukgx",
    storageBucket: "d-ucukgx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1031835936266"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);



  const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
export const ChampsRef = databaseRef.child("Champs");


export const authRef = firebase.auth();
export const timeRef = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

export default databaseRef;
```

config/dev.js

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";



  var firebaseConfig2 = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDsTsClk8l2l5yLNu_eG-R06Usv4Oi_NvQ",
    authDomain: "d-ucukgx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://d-ucukgx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "d-ucukgx",
    storageBucket: "d-ucukgx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1031835936266"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2);




var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, "auth");
export default app;
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling initializeApp potentially a total 3 times here.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use the same config for 2 `intializeApp` just initialize it once and then export your `app`

You have to give your second `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2)` a name after your config. So it would look something like this.

`firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, 'secondary');`

You can read this post to know more about it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multiple app in the same project then you have to give each app instance a unique name like this:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'appA');
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, 'appB');
```